# css is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um array de itens que quero mudar o `css` no `scroll` do meu Documento, quando eu dou um `console.log()`, os itens estão lá, mas no loop para mudar o estilo deles, me da a mensagem:

> Uncaught TypeError: itensmenu[i].css is not a function

Chamada do evento `Scroll`:

```
 $(document).scroll(function(){
       var brand  = $('#brand');
       var posicao = window.pageYOffset;
       var navbar = $('#navbar');
       var itensmenu = $(".nav-item");
       var topo = $("#topo");
       trocaNav(navbar, topo, posicao, brand, itensmenu);

    });
```

Loop:

```
function trocaNav(navbar, topo, posicao, brand, itensmenu){
  if (posicao == 0){
    navbar.css("background-color", "transparent");
    brand.attr("src","img/logo_BP.png");
  } else{
    navbar.css("background-color", "white");
    brand.attr("src","img/logo.png");
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < itensmenu.length; i++){
    if (posicao == 0) {
      itensmenu[i].css("background-color", "white");
      itensmenu[i].css("color" , "white" );
    } else{
      itensmenu[i].css("background-color", "black");
      itensmenu[i].css("color", "black");         
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O uso de `[index]` no jQuery DOM só funciona para pegar o primeiro item, pois é um "atalho", para pegar outros itens deve usar ou `.each` ou `.eq`

Faça assim:

> `.eq` retorna o objeto jQuery e `.get` retorna o elemento DOM

```
  for(var i = 0; i < itensmenu.length; i++){
    var current = itensmenu.eq(i);

    if (posicao == 0) {
      current.css("background-color", "white");
      current.css("color" , "white" );
    } else{
      current.css("background-color", "black");
      current.css("color", "black");         
    }
  }
```

Ou melhor seria assim:

```
var bg = "white", cor = "white";

if (posicao == 0) {
    bg = "black";
    cor = "black";
}

for(var i = 0; i < itensmenu.length; i++){
  var current = itensmenu.eq(i);

  current.css("background-color", bg);
  current.css("color", cor);
}
```

Ou assim, com `.each`:

```
var bg = "white", cor = "white";

if (posicao == 0) {
    bg = "black";
    cor = "black";
}

itensmenu.each(function (i) {
  $(this).css({
      "background-color": bg,
      "color": cor
  });
});
```

Comment: Fiz algumas adaptações, da terceira forma funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o retorno é diferente, mas neste caso também funcionaria com certeza http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709660/jquery-eq-vs-get já apago o comment

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ok, mas sempre podes colocar esse acrescento, teria mais visibilidade

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento de nada, rica resposta